# Fibration on the category of Lie pseudoalgebras implementing comorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ct.category-theory, lie-algebroids, fibered-categories

I am trying to understand comorphisms of Lie pseudoalgebras from the point of view of fibred categories, but failing miserably so far. My question would be:

*Is there a (op)fibration $\mathrm{LiePs} \to \mathrm{Alg}$ of the category of Lie pseudoalgebras in the sense of (op)fibred categories such that comorphisms of Lie pseudoalgebras are morphisms in the dual fibration $\mathrm{LiePs}^*$?*

Let me be a bit more precise:
Lie pseudoalgebras (aka Lie-Rinehart algebras or others) can be seen as the algebraic counterparts of Lie algebroids.

> **Definition: (Lie Pseudoalgebra)**
> A *Lie pseudoalgebra* consists of a commutative algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$,
> such that $\mathfrak{g}$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module and $\mathcal{A}$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ by
> derivations, i.e. we have a Lie algebra morphism $\rho \colon \mathfrak{g} \to 
> \mathrm{Der}(\mathcal{A})$ which is also an $\mathcal{A}$-module morphism and we have
> $$ [\xi_1, a \xi_2] = a[\xi_1,\xi_2] + \rho(\xi_1)(a)\xi_2$$
> for $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in \mathfrak{g}$, $a \in \mathcal{A}$.

For Lie pseudoalgebras there is a quite obvious notion of morphism.

> **Definition: (Morphism of Lie pseudoalgebras)**
> A morphism of Lie pseudoalgebras $(\mathcal{A},\mathfrak{g})$ and $(\mathcal{B},\mathfrak{h})$ consists
> of an algebra morphism $\phi \colon \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ and a module morphism
> $\Phi \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{h}$ along $\phi$ which is also a Lie algebra morphism and
> $$ \phi(\rho_{\mathcal{A}}(\xi)a) = \rho_{\mathcal{B}}(\Phi(\xi))\phi(a)$$
> holds for $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$, $a \in \mathcal{A}$.

Let us denote the category of Lie pseudoalgebras by $\mathrm{LiePs}$.
Then there is an obvious functor $\mathrm{LiePs} \to \mathrm{Alg}$ by mapping a Lie pseudoalgebra
$(\mathcal{A},\mathfrak{g})$ to the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and a morphism $(\Phi,\phi)$ to the corresponding algebra morphism $\phi$.

---

*Question 1:*
Is $\mathrm{LiePs} \to \mathrm{Alg}$ a (op)fibration of categories?

---

If so: for (op)fibred categories there is a notion of a dual (op)fibration, see e.g. [A.Kock; The dual fibration in elementary terms](https://users-math.au.dk/kock/fib9.pdf), whose morphisms can be understood as comorphisms of the original objects.
And there is a notion of comorphism of Lie pseudoalgebras, see e.g. [Z. Chen,Z.-J. Liu; On (co-)morphisms of Lie pseudoalgebras and groupoids](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.2149.pdf).

---

*Question 2:* Do comorphisms of Lie pseudoalgebras agree with morphisms in the dual fibration
$\mathrm{LiePs}^* \to \mathrm{Alg}$?

---

Comment: **Question:** "**Definition: (Lie Pseudoalgebra)**
A *Lie pseudoalgebra* consists of a commutative algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$,
such that $\mathfrak{g}$ is an $\mathcal{A}$-module and $\mathcal{A}$ acts on $\mathfrak{g}$ by
derivations, i.e. we have a Lie algebra morphism $\rho \colon \mathfrak{g} \to \mathrm{Der}(\mathcal{A})$ which is also an $\mathcal{A}$-module morphism and we have
$$ [\xi_1, a \xi_2] = a[\xi_1,\xi_2] + \rho(\xi_1)(a)\xi_2$$
for $\xi_1, \xi_2 \in \mathfrak{g}$, $a \in \mathcal{A}$." **Comment:** If $k \rightarrow B \xrightarrow f A$ is a map of c

Comment: @StefanKohl - when you turn something into a comment - can you include the entire message? If you look at the other answer you will observe that he is trying to answer a question that is not correctly phrased. He has not observed that the asker is using the wrong definition of a "morphism".

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer but this is how I would tackle this:

---

**Background knowledge:** Given a category $C$ and a (weak-) functor $F:C^{op}\to \mathrm{Cat}$ one can construct a category $$\int F$$ (also denoted $\int_C F$) called the [Grothendieck Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_construction) that comes with a canonical arrow $\pi_f:\int F\to C$ that happens to be a fibration. Inversely: Given a fibration $\pi: E\to C$ we can construct a (weak-) functor $F_\pi:C^{op}\to \mathrm{Cat}$. These two constructions are inverse in a suitable way. Similarly for covariant functors $F:C\to\mathrm{Cat}$.

---

**Now:** To check if your functor $\mathrm{LiePs}\to\mathrm{Alg}$ is a fibration I would try to construct $\mathrm{LiePs}$ as the Grothendieck Construction of a functor $$Ps:\mathrm{Alg}^{op}\to\mathrm{Cat}$$ (or maybe $Ps:\mathrm{Alg}\to\mathrm{Cat}$).

The object part of this functor should be

$$Ps: A \mapsto \mathrm{Lie}^*_{/\mathrm{Der}(A)}$$ where $\mathrm{Lie}^*_{/\mathrm{Der}(A)}$ is a suitable subcategory of the comma category $\mathrm{Lie}_{/\mathrm{Der}(A)}$. A nice feature of the Grothendieck Construction is the following: If your functor actually is a fibration, you should then be able to extend this assignment to a weak functor in a more or less obvious way: For every morphism $f:A\to B$ in $\mathrm{Alg}$ you would search for a functor $f^*:\mathrm{Ps}(B)\to \mathrm{Ps}(B)$ (Or maybe covariantly $f_*:\mathrm{Ps}(A)\to \mathrm{Ps}(B)$?).

The next step is to check if the resulting category $\int Ps$ is the "same" as $\mathrm{LiePs}$. From the construction of $\int Ps$ there should already by suitable candidates for the equivalence functors.